# ActiveMQ move expired messages to different queue than failed messages

Tags: java, activemq-classic

I have a use case where there may be a build up of messages on an ActiveMQ  queue. The goal is to have higher priority, newer messages executed first. High priority messages older than some time should be executed at a lower priority.

From what I have read, the JMS selector does not support a concept of NOW(); (i.e.)

```
JMSTimestamp < NOW() - 30 MINUTES
```

I read a suggestion to use expire time. From my understanding of the [redelivery policy](http://activemq.apache.org/message-redelivery-and-dlq-handling.html), expired messages go to the same queue as failed messages. Is there a way to have expired messages move to a different queue (queue.A) then failed messages (DLQ)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ActiveMQ 5.x there isn't a way that I can think to do this using the standard set of broker configuration options.  That said you could always write your own BrokerPlugin that does something along these lines by intercepting expired messages and sending them off someplace else.

If you are using ActiveMQ Artemis then you can do this quite easily by configuring it to do what you want, the [Failed Delivery](https://activemq.apache.org/artemis/docs/latest/undelivered-messages.html) and [Expiry](https://activemq.apache.org/artemis/docs/latest/message-expiry.html) address configurations allow you do handle this scenario.